# Alert sound with AlertDialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

below code is just to show AlertDialog when button is clicked in flutter and I'm searching the way to trigger device's alert sound when alert dialog pops up for both Android and iOS. I tried search pub.dev for package or other website for related topic but nothing found so far.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Application',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showAlertDialog(context);
      },
      child: const Text('Press button'),
    );
  }
}

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  Widget button = TextButton(
    child: const Text('OK'),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
  );

  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("Alert title"),
    content: const Text('Alert message.'),
    actions: [
      button,
    ],
  );

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ringtone player package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player).

```
import 'package:flutter_ringtone_player/flutter_ringtone_player.dart';

// Call on 'onPressed' to play system default notification sound.
FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();

// Call on 'onPressed' to play a specific sound.
FlutterRingtonePlayer.play(
  android: AndroidSounds.notification,
  ios: IosSounds.glass,
  looping: true, // Android only - API >= 28
  volume: 0.1, // Android only - API >= 28
  asAlarm: false, // Android only - all APIs
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the audio player package to play alert audio when you open the alert box -- https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: Thank you @tk_tanz. I had a look at it earlier but had an impression this only works with audio file in assets. I was hoping something that can use device's native sound. I tried SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.alert) in flutter/services.dart but it doesn't work for me. I saw quite a few claims it doesn't work on github thread and I'm not sure it will work if I wait.